# jQuery setting params to the next page

Tags: jquery, parameters, reload

Here's the situation: I have a form in pop up (which is being shown on click). After submit page is naturally reloaded (and I unfortunately cannot use AJAX `:(`). So I wonder if there is any way that I can check if the form was submitted last time page reloaded?
I mean smth lake that:

```
if (lastPage(formSubmitted)) {
   doStuff();
}
```

Thank you for attention.

Comment: 'and I unfortunately cannot use AJAX :(' why?

Comment: I am using foreign CMS, they ain't got one :(

Comment: atleast they have got JQUERY rite??

Comment: jQuery does not depend on cms, it depends on js files. And also I tagged this question as jQuery, so I am using it.

Comment: If you not using ajax, i prefer storing flag bit in session during the form is submitted. Then, assign the flag bit to hidden input on page load. After that in your javascript "if" condition, check for that hidden input status.

Comment: Thank you, you have proven what i was thinking about.